# Is there a difference between "only if $P$, then $Q$" and "if and only if $P$, then $Q$"?

Tags: logic, terminology

The way I understand it currently, saying "*only if $P$, then $Q$*" is like saying that "*only if $P$ happens, $Q$ happens.*" To me, it seems to say the same thing as "*if and only if* $P$ *happens*, $Q$ *happens*."

> Does saying "*if and only if $P$, then $Q$ "* have the same meaning as
>   saying "*only if $P$, then $Q$"*?

Comment: "if and only if P, then Q" is clearly ambiguous. It must be either "Q if and only if P" or "if P, then Q"-

Answer (score 7):

No. *Only if* $P$, *then* $Q$ means that $Q$ cannot happen without $P$:  if $Q$ happens, $P$ must have happened. It does **not** say that if $P$ happens, then $Q$ must also happen. It’s exactly equivalent to $Q$ *implies* $P$. Note that this is a true statement if $P$ occurs and $Q$ does not.

*If and only if* $P$, *then* $Q$ says that if $Q$ occurs, then $P$ must have occurred, **and** if $P$ occurs, then $Q$ will also occur: it’s exactly equivalent to saying that either both $P$ and $Q$ occur, or neither occurs. If $P$ occurs and $Q$ does not, this statement is false.

In symbols, the first statement reduces to $Q\Rightarrow P$ and the second to $Q\Leftrightarrow P$.

Answer (score 1):

"Only if $P$, then $Q$" basically means "$Q$ implies $P$" from a logical standpoint. "If and only if $P$, then $Q$" means that "$P$ implies $Q$ and $Q$ implies $P$".

Symbolically we write these as "$Q \implies P$" and "$P \iff Q$", respectively. The latter could be written as two statements as well: "$P \implies Q \land Q \implies P$".

Answer (score 1):

A number greater than two is prime *only if* it is odd. True. [If it were even it would be divisible by two and not a prime.]

A number great than two is prime *if and only if* it is odd. False. [9 is odd and greater than two but not prime.]

A two-way conditional requires more for its truth than a one-way conditional!

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly cases where the use of 'only if' is meant as 'if and only if'. For example, if a professor tells you that "Sorry, but you can take my course Calculus II only if you have taken Calculus I", the professor probably means an if and only if: taking Calculus I would be necessary ... but it would probably also be sufficient, or else the professor would probably have mentioned any other prerequisites as well. I certainly would be pretty pissed (and rightfully so) if, after having taken Calculus I, I go back to this professor, only to be told that "Oh, but you still can't get in, because you also need to have taken Algebra".

But, there are also cases where the 'only if' is clearly *not* meant as an 'if and only if': something can be a square only if it has four sides ... but clearly not anything with four sides is a square.